# Migrate from JavaDB to PostgreSQL and cant access database any longer

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jdbc, glassfish

I have an application on Glassfish v2 ( on Mac OS 10.5.8 and Java 1.6 ) that uses JavaDB and Toplinks that comes with the Glassfish bundle. Everything works fine.

I have installed PostgreSQL 8.4 and the JDBC v4 driver. Both Glassfish and Postgres server run on localhost. From Netbeans, I create a connection to a database on the Postgres server, and it works fine, I can manually create and delete tables.

I create a connection pool, resource and persistence unit for this connection to the Posgres server. When I deploy I have the following error :

```
ADM1041:Sent the event to instance:
    [ResourceDeployEvent -- reference-added jdbc/jdbc/MyDatasource]
CORE5004: Resource Deployed: [jdbc:jdbc/MyDatasource].
TopLink, version: Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.1 (Build b60e-fcs (12/23/2008))
Server: unknown
RAR5038:Unexpected exception while creating resource for pool MyConnectionPool.  
Exception : Connection could not be allocated because: 
    FATAL: database "null" does not exist
```

I read that with Postgres 8.4, localhost request are accepted by default, so I haven't changed anything in postgres.conf.

I am missing something, but I cant see what.
Thanks in advance for any hint.

Tart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ensure that MacOSX/GlassFish really uses the specified Java version (test with: **java -version**). Then try the following:

```
asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool 
   --datasourceclassname org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource 
   --restype javax.sql.DataSource --property portNumber=5432:password=secret:user=postgres:serverName=localhost:databaseName=postgres 
   test-pool
```

and

```
asadmin create-jdbc-resource --connectionpoolid test-pool jdbc/Postgres
```

remember to change the **username**, **password**, **server**, **port** and **database** to reflect your setup. Then test the datasource using:

```
asadmin ping-connection-pool test-pool
```

if this does not work then you have miss-configured your data source.

Comment: The first phrase makes no sense. JDBC4 requires Java SE 6, not Java EE 6. Java EE 5 can run perfectly on top of Java SE 6. This is not the problem.

Comment: Thanks. The driver was actually correct, but creating the ConnectionPool directly in the JavaEE server instead of doing via Netbeans worked. I am not sure what I did wrong setting the ConnectionPool via the wizard in Netbeans though, but at least the problem is solved :o)

Comment: fixed the the JDBC driver version part, as correctly pointed out by BalusC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the stack, but it sounds like you haven't specified the database name in the connection. See http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/84/connect.html for a list of parameters you can/should set on the connection.

Comment: I think the connection is ok, as I can manually access the database using it. It is define this way :
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/MyDB"/>
    <property name="User" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="Password" value="foo"/>